# JavaScript disabled on Firefox meaning my buttons don't work, is there a way to write the buttons such that they will work?

Tags: javascript, php, firefox, button

So I have written a basic page which has buttons:

```
<button type="button" onclick="minus()"> </button>
```

with the script:

```
function minus() {
  if (<?php echo $number ?> > 1){
  var num = <?php echo $number; ?> - 1;
  var number=num;
  window.location.href = "page2.php?w1=" + number;}
};
```

So this just subtracts 1 off of a PHP variable and it works perfectly well in Chrome, IE and Safari, but in Firefox it doesn't work at all. Is this a security thing is this code particularly insecure?.

Is there any way in which I can write a button to change this PHP variable without using JavaScript as to make it work on Chrome, IE, Safari + Firefox?

Many thanks

Comment: It is not Java, it is JavaScript method. You need to write valid JavaScript code and then it will work. Check if FF indicates that there are JavaScript errors in your page

Comment: also dont use term `java` for `javascript`

Comment: you can't use javascript if it is not enabled. You cannot force it to work, it would be a security issue. You would need to have a fallback function for when javascript isn't available, which should be ye old postbacks

Comment: Sorry, honest mistake I'm just trying to learn. Could you advise on why the JavaSript doesn't seem to run in firefox?

Comment: @user3412782: What is your console error? Also, what does your source code look like (after the PHP has been rendered... View Source)

Comment: Haha: *`"is this code particularly insecure?"`*... "Does my bum look fat in this function?

Comment: Ok thank you all for pointing out Java and Javascript aren't the same, it is noted :). The Javascript works flawlessly in Chrome, IE and Safari thus I don't believe it to be an issue directly with the script. I believe it is because Javascript is disabled, how can I write a back up function for case where Javascript is disabled (or what should I search to find out please?)?

Comment: No console error, it just doesn't do anything

Comment: @user3412782: Does any javascript work for you in firefox? Just test a simple alert. Also, [maybe this is the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275092/windows-location-href-not-working-on-firefox3)?

Comment: Yes some does, I just tested the confirm command and that worked fine. But I have just noticed some of my CSS 'hover' styles aren't working in FF when they're surrounded by the <button> tags.

Comment: I've found FF requires the div to be positioned relatively and not absolutely for the button to work. I've shown it below :) thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server-side language - JavaScript a client-side language; PHP is executed before Javascript, so by the time your Javascript function is initiated the PHP code is already gone.

Take a look at this: [Using PHP in javascript's IF Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379058/using-php-in-javascripts-if-statement).

It might help!

Comment: Thank you for your input :) it turns out the reason it wasn't working was FF requires that button div's are    position:relative; otherwise it doesn't seem to work, but with that positioning it works now.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue (or at least a solution I have found to work) is for the positioning of the div which is the button to be set to relative (note I have only found FF to require this IE, Chrome and Safari don't seem to be affected by position:absolute). i.e.

```
<button type="button" onclick="someFunction()">
<div id="button"></div>
</button>
```

with the CSS being:

```
#button {
position:relative
}
```

and the hover styling applied to the button element instead of the div.